Step 2 in Theorem 16.5 In The Book “Analysis On Manifolds” by James R. Munkres.
I have encountered an issue that I need help with. On page 142, step 2 seems incomplete or incorrect at first. So, I tried to find the PDF version of the book. Upon checking the PDF version of another edition of the book, published in 1991, I discovered that some contents in step 2, theorem 16.5 are missing, exactly different, from my copy (published in 1998 by CRC Press).
(After posting the question, I have found the PDF of the same edition. And the step 2 in the PDF is concise like mine, and hence it is not a misprint only of my book.)
Here is a comparison for clarity:

Photo of My Book (Page 142, Step 2):
enter image description here

Screenshot from the PDF (Page 142, Step 2):
enter image description here


As you can see, the step 2 in the first picture is very shortened, and looks visually awkward. Nevertheless, I think this omission is correct. In other words, CRC Press (or Munkres) might have modified the part intentionally for some reasons (to simplify or correct the step 2 in the second picture)
Therefore, I have two questions:

Is the step 2 in the first picture is correct?
Is the step 2 in the second picture is correct?

Thank you in advance for your help!
Here is the whole proof of the theorem 16.5 in the book published in 1991. The step 2 is the only part different from the one published by CRC Press:




Weird question. If you do have the pdf, that surely means that there exists a "corrected" version. You are overthinking this. It is just a printing mistake. Study the missing parts from the pdf i guess?

@JonathanZ Seems to be Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds. https://archive.org/details/MunkresJ.R.AnalysisOnManifoldsTotal/page/n153/mode/2up

Yes. Annoying. At least they left the white space there for you to fill it in.

Could be a misprint, could be two different editions.

@noobman Since I'm not very familiar with English, I think the intention has changed because I'm getting help from ChatGPT. First, I want to know if such omissions are also found in other people's books. (Perhaps the book published by CRC Press might have similar errors like mine.) Second, I think such omissions could be intentional. In the first picture, notice that it ends with "the integral of f over A by the comparison property."

@noobman In the second picture, it ends with "the integral of f over D by the comparison property, less than the integral of f over A." Therefore, I wanted to ask if the first picture might not just be a printing mistake but actually logically correct. And it seems a bit awkward to label other missing parts in step 2 simply as printing mistakes or errata as well.  In summary, I think the step 2 in the first picture appears to be correct.

Every math book, in every language, has mistakes: simple misprints or typographical errors, stupid elementary math mistakes, simple mistakes of logic. Every book. Sometimes authors get a chance to correct their mistakes and publish a second edition. Sometimes they don't.

On top of that, since the beginning of books, one can get badly copied editions of a book, produced by human beings who are careless in the copying process and who thereby introduce more errors in the copying process. Sometimes one can allay that by making sure your copy is authorized (i.e. is approved by the author).
